# $f$ is an odd, $2\pi$ periodic function. Write explicitly

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be an odd $2\pi$ periodic function defined on $(0,\pi)$ by $f(x) = \frac12 (\pi - x)$.

I am asked to "write $f$ explicitly". what does this mean? how to do that? thanks for help.

Comment: What about $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$$ ? Is it explicit enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the question asks for an explicit formula for all the real numbers $(-\infty,\infty)$.

It is an odd function, meaning $f(x) = -f(-x)$ for all $x$, therefore $f(0) = -f(0) = 0$. Therefore we have its values for $(-\pi,\pi)$. Because of the periodicity, this automatically gives us the values for the function for all $x\neq \pi n$ where $n\in N$.

From periodicity and oddness we get $f(-\pi) = f(\pi) = -f(-\pi) = 0$. So we have the values set for a complete $2\pi$ period $(-\pi,\pi]$.

To write a truly explicit formula for $f(x)$ we have to give an explicit formula representing the annoying periodicity, meaning we'd want to deal only with $x -2\pi\lfloor \frac{x} {2\pi} \rfloor$. Note $x + 2\pi n -2\pi\lfloor \frac{x + 2\pi n} {2\pi} \rfloor = x + 2\pi n -2\pi(\lfloor \frac{x +n} {2\pi} \rfloor + n) = x -2\pi\lfloor \frac{x} {2\pi} \rfloor$.

This leaves us with the following function:

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
     \hfill \frac{1}{2}\left(\pi-\left(x -2\pi\lfloor \frac{x} {2\pi} \rfloor\right)\right)    \hfill & \text{ if } x\neq2n\pi \\
      \hfill 0 \hfill & \text{ if } x=2n\pi \\
\end {cases}
 $$
Where $n$ is an integer. Note that $f(nπ)$ still equals $0$.

This function would also work: 
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
     \hfill -\arctan \left(\tan \left(\frac{x+\pi }{2}\right)\right)    \hfill & \text{ if } x\neq2n\pi \\
      \hfill 0 \hfill & \text{ if } x=2n\pi \\
\end {cases}
 $$

Comment: Can you please explain why you put integer part of $x/(2\pi)$

Comment: This is because I want $f(x)$ to be periodic for $2 \pi$. This means that I want a function that only "knows" how much it is modulo $2 \pi$. It is more intuitive to think of a function that I want to be periodic with period 10. Essentially, that would mean I am only interested in $x \mod 10$ (the remainder), which means I want to "throw out" the integer number of times 10 is in $x$.

Comment: You're absolutely correct :). I'll rectify the answer.

Comment: Your final formula doesn't give $f(0) = 0$. I didn't check the derivation closely so I'm not sure what went wrong.

Comment: Right again. The final function has to "special case" the $f(2 \pi n)$ because the $f(0) = 0$ implies it isn't even continuous there. The value we deduced there wasn't from the original formula but from the oddness. In the odd $n$ they actually agree.

Answer (score 1):

An explicit expression for the function is:
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
            f(x+2(\kappa+1)\pi), \ \ x\in\big(-2(\kappa+1)\pi,-2\kappa\pi\big), \\
            \frac{1}{2}(\pi-x), \ \ x\in(0,2\pi),   \\
            f(x-2\kappa\pi) \ \ x\in\big(2\kappa\pi,2(\kappa+1)\pi\big)
            \end{array}
      \right. \Rightarrow $$

$$ \Rightarrow 
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
            -\frac{1}{2}\big(x+(2\kappa+1)\pi\big), \ \ x\in\big(-2(\kappa+1)\pi,-2\kappa\pi\big), \\
            \frac{1}{2}(\pi-x), \ \ x\in(0,2\pi),   \\
            \frac{1}{2}\big((2\kappa+1)\pi-x\big), \ \ x\in\big(2\kappa\pi,2(\kappa+1)\pi\big)
            \end{array}
      \right.
$$
for any real $x\neq\kappa\pi$ ($\kappa$ any non-negative integer). 
The function finally looks like: 
     [image: graph]

(with the integer multiples of $\pi$ excluded).

Note that the geometric properties should now be obvious from the graph: the function is periodic, with period $2\pi$ and also odd, which is equivalent to the fact that its graph is symmetric with respect to the origin.